# Want to Increment ID of one DIV in Specific time interval in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<pre><div id='my_id1'></div></pre>
```

I want to increment by 1+ in loop in specific time  example on same div  after 3 second is there any way to do this in Jquery please help me i am very beginner in java script
Please

Comment: `setInterval(function() { // Code }, 3000);`

Comment: That i know its java script  time interval function but i need to increment div id by +1 each time . Did you know how can i do this in jquery..

Answer (score 0):

```
var dynID;
setInterval(function() { 
    dynID = $('div').attr('id');
    dynID = dynID.substring(dynID.indexOf('d')+1);
    dynID = parseInt(dynID,10);
    dynID = dynID + 1;
    $('div').attr('id' , 'my_id' + dynID);
    console.log(dynID);
}, 3000);
```

Is this what you wanted?

https://jsfiddle.net/sthsuuec/8/

Comment: Wow excellent this is i want thanks for your valuable time for sharing this information to me i really appreciate it........

Answer (score -1):

```
var index=0;
var interval=setInterval(function() { 
  index++;
  console.log("<pre><div id='my_id"+index+"'></div></pre>");
  if(index===5){
    stopInt();
  }
}, 1000);

function stopInt(){
  clearInterval(interval);
}
```

Above code working [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2tgjzuy5/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, sure i will fallow from next post.